# Who is Mother Weather, to which some people refer in their essays or posts?

Tags: goddesses

Is this the same as Mother Nature?

And here are some examples.

[Don’t Mess with Mother Weather By Vicki Lathom](https://newsfromthebow.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/dont-mess-with-mother-weather-by-vicki-lathom/)

[Just because...](https://elengrey.com/2008/07/31/just-because/)

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'd say it's a local thing. For example, a classic belief in Christian Catholic parts of Germany makes Saint Peter responsible for the weather, while classic German folklore has Mother Hulda send the snow in winter.